# Select approved comments and unapproved comments of current user MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join

I'm new to mysql and I have a problem with selecting data from mysql database:

```
$post_id = 3;
$current_user_id = 1;

$query = "SELECT `comments`.*, `users`.`username`, `users`.`image` FROM (`comments`)
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `comments`.`post_id` =  '$post_id'
AND `comments`.`status` =  1
AND `users`.`status` =  1
ORDER BY `comments`.`date` desc";
```

This select, selects all approved comments from database, but also, in this select, I need all unapproved comments of $current_user_id,

Result must look like:

[all approved post comments] + [all unapproved post comments of $current_user_id]

Comment: if you can build the schema on http://sqlfiddle.com and share, it will be very useful to anyone trying to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

not sure if this will really work, but just give a try and see. I can't test the query since we don't have the schema.

```
SELECT `comments`.*, `users`.`username`, `users`.`image` FROM (`comments`)
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `comments`.`post_id` =  '$post_id'
AND (
   (`comments`.`status` =  1 AND `users`.`status` =  1)
  OR
   ( `comments`.`status` =  0 AND `users`.`id`= '$current_user_id' )
)
ORDER BY `comments`.`date` desc
```

What I thought is select all the `approved comments` OR ( comments that are not approved, but from this user ). You might have to alter the query till you get what you really needed, I'm just giving you the idea, not the exact query. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your code looks simple and works just fine 
Thanks you save my time

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `comments`.*, `users`.`username`, `users`.`image` FROM (`comments`)
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `comments`.`post_id` =  '$post_id'
AND `comments`.`status` =  1
AND `users`.`status` =  1
UNION ALL
SELECT `comments`.*, `users`.`username`, `users`.`image` FROM (`comments`)
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `comments`.`post_id` =  '$post_id'
AND `comments`.`status` =  0
AND `users`.`id` = '$current_user_id'
ORDER BY `comments`.`date` desc
```